# How to use dynamic values in JSL in a JSR-352 Java Batch application

Tags: java-ee-7, jsr352, java-batch

Is there a syntax to use dynamic values in the JSL ([Job Specification Language](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/batch-processing004.htm)) file of a [JSR-352](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=352) Java Batch application?

My specific case is to be able to change the value of the `item-count` attribute in my `chunk` element on the fly (no code change, no re-build, no re-deploy...).

Comment: This has been raised as a candidate for improvement before.   It's currently tracked in Jakarta Batch as:  https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/batch-api/issues/95

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of the 4 property substitutions to achive that. See JSR 352 spec document 8.8.1 Substitution Processing Rules.

> 1. jobParameters - specifies to use a named parameter from the job parameters.
> 2. jobProperties - specifies to use a named property from among the job's properties.
> 3. systemProperties - specifies to use a named property from the system properties.
> 4. partitionPlan - specifies to use a named property from the partition plan of a partitioned step.

For example,

```
item-count = ="#{jobParameters['item-count']}"
```

If this is not what you want, please elaborate your specific use case.